# Is this flicker a common issue in react-native-image-crop-picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image-crop-picker

I have been trying to look for a solution for this problem. When using react-native-image-crop-picker to pick an image, if you use the cropper, once you click on choose there is a fast flicker of the gallery screen before you are back to the screen from where you choose the image?

I have looked at a tutorial on youtube and also saw that flicker in there.

Does anyone know if this is a common issue or is there something that can be done to solve it?

Comment: experiencing this as well